# C# What event do I use to do something when a button is created?

Tags: c#, button, ping

Ok, I am not sure how to do this as I am trying to teach myself C# and create a program for work at the same time.

I have a List of IP addresss:

```
List<IPAddress> addresses
```

I have a group of buttons being created for these ip addresses dynamically on the fly once the list is submitted to the form.

What Event do I need to use to launch a function to do something when that button is created?

More Info:
The List of IP Addresses is iterated through and button is created for each of those IP Addrsses inside a TableLayoutPanel.

When those buttons are created on the form inside the panel, I want a function called that will pass the IPAddress in the:

```
b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2], ba[3]);
```

and asynchronously ping that IP Address.

If the Ping returns true I want the button to turn green from its default color.
If the ping returns false I want the button to turn red from its default color.

EDIT:::::
I will just add the code I have right now creating the FLP, TBL, and Buttons.  When each button is created I want to call a ping function to ping the IPaddress for that button and change its color based on how the ping returned.  I don't know how to set it up or what the function will really look like either.  I have tried b.control.added but it never gets triggered.  It will trigger if I do tbl.control.added only then it doesn't have the information I need to pass to the function (the IPAddress) or does it?  Like I said really new to C# and haven't really programmed much since 2005 so way out of the game.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(List<IPAddress> addresses)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    flp.AutoScroll = true;
    flp.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
    flp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 67);
    flp.AutoSize = true;
    flp.Height = 600;
    flp.WrapContents = false;
    foreach (var ipa in addresses)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp.AutoSize = true;
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlp.RowCount = 0;
        tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnCount = 0;
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 40);
        lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 50);
        lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        Byte[] ba = ipa.GetAddressBytes();
        lbl.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2], ba[3]);
        tlp.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, 0);
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Router\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.126", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.126", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        b.Click += btnRouter_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        b.ControlAdded += btnRouter_ControlAdded;
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 1, 0);
        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Switch\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.57", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.57", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        b.Click += btnSwitch_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        b.ControlAdded += btnSwitch_ControlAdded;
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 2, 0);
        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Steelhead\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.7", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.7", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]); 
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        b.Click += btnSteelhead_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        b.ControlAdded += btnSteelhead_ControlAdded;
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 3, 0);
        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "InPath\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.8", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.8", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        b.Click += btnInPath_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        b.ControlAdded += btnInPath_ControlAdded;
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 4, 0);
        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Server\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.6", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.6", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  //       b.Click += btnServer_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        b.ControlAdded += btnServer_ControlAdded;
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 5, 0);
        b = new Button();
        b.Text = "NCAP";
        b.Tag = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
        b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        b.Click += btnNCAP_Click;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
        tlp.Controls.Add(b, 6, 0);
        flp.Controls.Add(tlp);
    }
    this.AutoSize = true;
    this.Controls.Add(flp);
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need an event?  Just call the function when you create the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ControlAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded(v=vs.110).aspx) Event of your TableLayoutControl, the ControlEventArgs has a Control Property which is the Control that was added. This is a quick and dirty example of what you are wanting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication75
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        List<IPAddress> addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Add IpAddresses to the List
            addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 65, 55, 72, 135 }));
            addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 8, 8, 8, 8 })); 
            addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 74, 125, 157, 99 }));
            addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 98, 137, 149, 56 }));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Not sure how you are passing in your list I elected to do it with a button click
            foreach (var address in addresses)
            {
                byte[] ba = address.GetAddressBytes(); //Get the IPAddress in a Byte Format for the Button Text
                                                       //Keeping it as an IPAddress in the Tag so I don't have to convert later
                Button b = new Button() { Tag = address, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2], ba[3]) };
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
            }


        }

        private void tableLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is Button) //Check if control is a Button.
            {     
                //The ControlEventArgs Control Property has the Control that was added to the tableLayoutPanel
                Ping pingIt = new Ping(); //Create the Ping Object
                pingIt.PingCompleted += pingIt_PingCompleted;  //Add the eventHandler
                //used the SendAsync Method that allows and object to be passed as a user token
                //passed in the control that was added so that the background color can be changed
                pingIt.SendAsync((IPAddress)e.Control.Tag,2000,e.Control);
            }

        }

        void pingIt_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = (Control)e.UserState;
            if (ctrl.Text != "NCAP")
            {
                if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example running:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't your code effect every control added to the tablelayoutpanel? Even the label and the last button (NCAP) that I don't want the background changed on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want, but I think my guidance help you.

with this following code you can add a button to your form dynamically:

```
        //instantiate and initialize your button
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = "btnShaun";
        b.Text = "SomthingYouWant";

        //in here you add this button to your form
        this.Controls.Add(b);

        //and here you set it's position in your form
        this.Controls["btnShaun"].Location = new Point(200, 100);
```

Now, The class `Form` have a `Event` called `ControlAdded`. here is VS Description for this `Event`:

```
"Occures when a control is added to this control"
```

so you can use your function in this event

Comment: I have tried that actually but 
b.ControlAdded += btnTest_ControlAdded;
never gets triggered, only if I name it 
tbl.ControlAdded += btnRouter_ControlAdded;
and then It doesn't get the ip address information given to b.tag.

Answer (score 0):

The Form has a ControlAdded event that you can use for this purpose.  But I'm unclear why you would need to do that.  Just call b.Tag = ... when you create the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code, check how I have added ControlAdded event handler.
ControlAdded event handler to be attached to parent or container in which control is being added, not to control (button) itself.

In your case handler need to be attached to the panel you are using. you can also use designer window for this.

In this example I have attached it to form1(this).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<IPAddress> addresses;


        IPHostEntry heserver = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.254");
        addresses = heserver.AddressList.ToList();

        int count = 0;

        this.ControlAdded += new  System.Windows.Forms.ControlEventHandler(this.button_added);

        foreach (var addr in addresses)
        {
            count += 1;
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Name = "button1";
            b.Text = addr.ToString();
            b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100 + ((count-1) * 100), 50);
            b.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        }           
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 1 clicked");
    }

    private void button_added(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button 1 added");
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the parent control's [`ControlAdded` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded.aspx), as other answers have suggested. This will work, but it seems inelegant to me. The parent should not be responsible for implementation details of its children. In fact, good design dictates that it not only be not responsible, but that it *not even know about* such things.

A better design would be to have the child controls handle this logic all on their own. To accomplish this, you'll need to create a custom class that inherits from the standard control. Then, in your custom control class, you will override the [`OnCreateControl` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol.aspx). From inside of that method, you can write code to do whatever initialization you want. (This is the same method that the WinForms framework uses to call the `OnLoad` method, which raises the `Load` event, for the `Form` class.)

The advantage of this design is that the logic is kept entirely self-contained. That means that (1) implementation details for the child controls don't have to leak out to the parent, and (2) *all* child controls of this type will behave in exactly the same way, without your having to duplicate the code.

It is worth nothing that there is *also* an [`OnHandleCreated` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onhandlecreated.aspx). This is called each time the control has to recreate its underlying Win32 window, which results in a new window handle. Technically, this is an implementation detail that you should be able to completely ignore. The handle can be recreated for multiple reasons without your explicit knowledge, for example, in response to your changing certain properties of the control. That means this method can be called multiple times during the control's lifetime. However, you will need to use this method instead of `OnCreateControl` if any of your logic requires access to the control's `Handle` property. Otherwise, prefer `OnCreateControl` for simplicity.

And actually, if all you're doing is setting the control's `Tag` property, you can do this in the custom control's *constructor*, without needing to override either the `OnCreateControl` or `OnHandleCreated` property. Setting the `Tag` property does not require that the control be created.

Comment: The tag property is already set from each control.  I am trying to find a way to change the background color of a button according to how a ping is returned to the IP addresses in the addresses list that was passed to the .tag property of the button.  I just can't/couldn't understand a way to trigger the Ping command when or just after the button was created.